# How to create a new GitHub repo from an existing one?

Tags: git, github

I have made major changes, used different tools and technologies in a repository, now I want to move it in a new repo with new name (off course), and keeping the original repo with its original state before making the changes, I haven't committed yet. I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: As an alternative, you could clone it and start using that location or you can create a branch and use the same repo but your new branch.

Comment: Consider if this is what you're after: 1) create the new (empty) github repository. 2) add this new repository as a remote to your local repository 3) push to the new remote. Obviously you would need to commit

Comment: Do you want to keep commit history of the current repo in the new one, or just the files?

Comment: @amenadiel just files

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I created new repo, added it to the local repo through this:
`git remote add origin https://github.com/me/newRepo.git` but gets error:
already exists

Comment: @Mohammed `git remote rm origin` first, or use a name other than `origin` for the new one.

Comment: You can only have one remote named `origin`, you already have one, try giving it a different name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Copy your current folder to a backup one. I don't want you to lose your code if something goes wrong.
2. Create a new repo in github (or wherever you want to). As you said, this new repo is  `https://github.com/me/newRepo.git`
3. Remove your current `.git` folder. Now your code is unversioned (and as @Zeplock said, the former commit history is gone for good)
4. Run `git init` to initialize an empty repository in your current folder
5. Run `git remote add origin https://github.com/me/newRepo.git` to point this new repo to its new origin

Comment: You should know that if you remove `.git` you will lose all of your commit history.

Comment: Yup. Read the comments in the question. It is what OP asked for